# Pi 3 running Buster - Mouse cursor jitters when switching states if FKMS is enabled

Tags: raspi-config, mouse

Title should be self-explanatory.

If FKMS, aka OpenGL, is enabled via `sudo raspi-config`, the mouse pointer "jumps", right after switching from one appearance state to another.

For example, when switching from normal to loading:

[image: mouse jitter 1]

Or, when switching from normal to text selection:

[image: mouse jitter 2]

Yes, these GIFs have been slowed down. In real time it takes about 1 or 2 frames.

Has anyone else experienced this before? And is there a way to fix it?