# Google Maps all garbled if GL is turned on

Tags: pi-4

P 4 running unmodified Raspbian (except FKMS is on), running Chromium.
Google Maps is unusable. This never occurred on my Pi 3.
[image]
Why is this happening, and is there any alternative to disabling GL via raspi-config?

Comment: Works fine on my Pi4 with Raspbian Buster. Is yours fully updated?

Comment: @CoderMike, Yes, it is fully updated and upgraded.  Have you turned on OpenGL using `sudo raspi-config`?

Comment: Yes, FKMS is on by default on the Pi4.

Comment: Did some troubleshooting - it turns out FKMS was not the cause, but a trigger. I deleted ~/.config/chromium and never saw the problem again.