# No display output if I start raspberry pi and then start the monitor

Tags: display, output

If I switch on monitor first then switch on raspberry pi, it works fine. But if I switch on raspberry pi and then monitor or switch on both pi and monitor simultaneously no display is shown on monitor.

** I use age old hp v194 18.5 inch monitor with a HDMI to vga converter.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same [problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103685/107602).
Solutions are:

1. Turn on the screen first. I give it 4 seconds. Slower SD cards won't have this problem, since the Pi waits longer before checking for a monitor.
2. Add/uncomment `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in `/boot/config.txt`.
3. Turn off OpenGL. `sudo raspi-config` --> Advanced Options --> GL Driver --> G1 Legacy.
4. Get a HDMI screen.